# Rails 3 before_filter after checking mobile device

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I'm not sure how to do chained filters here. Here is my code

```
  before_filter :prepare_for_mobile
  protect_from_forgery

  private

  def mobile_device?
    request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
  end
  helper_method :mobile_device?

  def prepare_for_mobile
    request.format = :mobile if mobile_device?
  end
```

What I want is after `:prepare_for_mobile` if it's not a mobile device it will redirect to a normal website and I would like to check if the user is logged in. On mobile version, no users will be required to log in.

And in the normal website, I would like to `:except` a particular controller as well.

How do I do that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a couple of things.... It looks like you're partially implementing the solution from Railscasts.com [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices) (only you're trying to do it without setting the session parameter??).

You don't need to 'chain' filters. Just create a new function (ex: get_ready) that calls the other two functions in the order you want them, and make that your filter.

```
before_filter :get_ready
protect_from_forgery

private

def get_ready
    prepare_for_mobile
    the_other_thing_you_want_to_chain
end

def mobile_device?
  request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
end
helper_method :mobile_device?

def prepare_for_mobile
  request.format = :mobile if mobile_device?
end

def the_other_thing_you_want_to_chain
   do_something unless mobile_device?
end
```

If you want to branch behavior within a single site based on mobile, you should do that in the controllers, in the routes, or both. I hope I answered your questions.